# Node JS - How to run cross browser testing in the same session one after one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor

I want to do cross browser testing but not together and not in a different

session, because I want all off the test result will generated to the same HTML 
report in the end of the session.

When I've tried to run all of them together part of the test cases are failed because time outs and the report was messy.

**Protractor - Conf:**

```
  multiCapabilities: [{
  'browserName': 'firefox',
      'cli': {
      'args': ['webdriver.firefox.useExisting=default']
      // 'args': ['webdriver.firefox.useExisting=default', '-jsconsole', '-jsdebugger']
}}, 

 {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
    args: ['--test-type','--memory-metrics','--console','--crash-on-failure'] 
    // '--load-extension=' + 'C:\\Users\\idan\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extensions\\idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj\\1.2.4_0'
  }
},

  {
      'browserName': 'internet explorer',
      'platform': 'ANY',
      'version': '11'
    }],


  // maxSessions: 1,
```

Comment: are you able to perform cross browser testing? and you just need help with reporting and stuff?

Comment: Yes I'm able to perform cross browser and just want to figure out how to run this testing not in multiple. And it must be in the same session because the testing report. Thanks @GirishSortur

Answer (score 0):

You can use browser.browserName for report names in order to have all reported, I use this function inside onPrepare():

```
browser.getCapabilities().then(function (cap) {
        console.log(cap);
        browser.browserName = cap.caps_.browserName;
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
            baseDirectory: 'target/'+browser.browserName+'/angular-test-result/',
            takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
            preserveDirectory: false
        }));
    });
```

Then if you don't want to run browsers in parallel you can call protractor with `-browser=chrome`

Comment: Thanks, Actually I already did it, but the problem is there any option to order the generated report and also the multi compatibility testing is very slow and a lot of test cases are failed because ot it. I want to figure out how can run cross browser one by one in a same session in order to oresnt all of the test results inside the generated report.. (every session is generating a new report)